# Make favorite star not filled in for jobs unless actually "Saved"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I clicked on a job ad and on the right side saw that the star was filled in.  It is a bit misleading because I immediately thought what is this I had never saved this job.  Come to find out the filled in star doesn't mean you saved it or Favorited it.

My suggestion is to make the star not filled in by default, it should only be the star shape with no filling.  Seeing the solid shape kind of steered my eyes to that direction.

[image]

Comment: Why does this specific star have to be different (the one next to your question is also filled in). Why not make it grey or something to make it look like it's disabled?

Comment: Sometimes SE feels like it should dogfood [ux.se]...

Comment: @AndréKool The difference is in shade. A dark blue filled in star makes it seem like it's filled in for a reason. A grey filled in star doesn't suggest that as much.